# Can't run certbot (on production)

Tags: python, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm getting this when I tried to run `certbot -h`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import zope.component
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from zope.interface import Interface
ImportError: No module named interface
```

I've tried reinstalling it. But doesn't help

Comment: have you tried all the possible solutions on their github issue page? https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2872 If you try something and it works, post the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Windows compatibility for `certbot` is a work in progress. You should consider installing and running on a Linux VM with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install certbot
```

Comment: I'm having this issue on ubuntu, on the server